# Where is the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, moon-phases

I live in Western Australia and I have not seen the moon for almost a solid week. Last I saw it it was almost full, and the sky has been clearer than ever with all the stars bright and visible yet the moon remains invisible. I heard there was a similar occurance in 2016 and wondering if this is the same thing, or should I be concerned?

Comment: The Moon is currently rising a couple of hours after midnight, and setting a couple of hours after midday. The rising & setting times get roughly 50 minutes later each day.

Comment: OMG SevenEves has started!

Answer (score 3):

Right now the moon is close to the sun in the sky, you can see it if you wake up early enough as a thin crescent. Moon rise on 19th May is at half past 3 in the morning.

This is not unusual, this happens every month.  (There's nothing to worry about)

It's close to midwinter in WA. On the 7th of May the moon was full, and (since a full moon is opposite the sun) the winter full moon is as high as summer sun. One week later and the moon was at "third quarter" and didn't rise until midnight. Even then it was hard to see until later, unless you have a clear eastern horizon.  Five days after that, the moon is hard to see at all, unless you get up before it gets light. Then on the 23rd of May is new moon, when the moon and sun rise together, and the moon can't be seen at all. But a few day's later you will see a thin crescent in the evening just at sunset.  Watch each night and you'll find that each night, the crescent grows in size and each night the moon sets later, until the 6th of June, when the moon will be full again, one moonth after the last full moon, and the cycle will begin again.

You can find details in almanacs like [time and date](https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/australia/perth?month=5). But there is greater comfort in watching the moon's regular monthly cycle.

Comment: Also, at Full Moon, the Moon rises when the Sun sets, and vice versa. But of course it's unusual for the exact instant of Full Moon to occur right at sunrise or sunset at a given location.